# fopen and fwrite inside for loop

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

```
for($i=0;$i<$directoriesCount;$i++)
{       
    $fileName=$Config['path']['basePath']."language/".$directories[$i]."/"."commontest.conf";
    $file = fopen($fileName,"a");
    $data = "testcontent";
    fwrite($file,"\n"); 
    fwrite($file,$data);
    fclose($file);
}
```

the `$directories` variable will have array values:

1. en_lang
2. fr_lang
3. it_lang, etc.,

in the every directory we should find the `commongtest.conf` file to write the content.

In my test file its writes only the first values of array for ex 1. en_lang folder file only get `fwrite` other files not affected.

Comment: You've got an extra double quote(") here ."/"."

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra double quote here:

```
."/".commontest.conf"
```

should be:

```
 ."/.commontest.conf"
```

A `foreach` statement might work better here for you:

```
foreach($directories as $directory){
  $fileName=$Config['path']['basePath']."language/".$directory."/.commontest.conf";
  $file = fopen($fileName,"a");
  $data = "testcontent"."\n"; 
  fwrite($file,$data);
  fclose($file);
}
```

This code is working for me.
I think using `file_put_contents` would be even better.

```
foreach($directories as $directory){
  $fileName=$Config['path']['basePath']."language/".$directory."/.commontest.conf";
  $data = "testcontent"."\n"; 
  file_put_contents($fileName,$data);
}
```

Comment: double quotes is typing mistake while typing here.... I will check with your code.... thanks for your reply...

Comment: I tried your code @Kaylined its not working for me... the first loop file only gets updated. other loop files does not get changed.

Comment: Is there more than 1 file in your array?

Comment: yes... 1. it_lang 2. en_lang 3. es_lang. the first it_lang inside file commontest.conf only get affected

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdc4feed46875559f92b2fd8c13dbe2952ab427b - it works; it generates 4 errors, as it should(1 for each iteration). There is something wrong with your array; can you show me a var_dump($directories); ??

Comment: now working fine with my own code.. it was not working with few logics in that code. thanks for your help...